# Split foreach results into reusable variables

Tags: php, foreach, split, var

I have a foreach function:

```
foreach ($result as $result) {
  echo "<a href='" . $result . "'>" . $result . "</a><br>";
}
```

Which generates a list like this:

```
[spacer]_[timespacer]_fiveseconds.wav
[trudy]_[0x06DDD12A]_i.wav
[trudy]_[0x06DDD12A]_get.wav
[spacer]_[timespacer]_halfsecond.wav
[spacer]_[timespacer]_onesecond.wav
```

I tried `explode` & `split` function but this constantly returns a whole list of:

```
array
array
```

What I want to achieve is to have `foreach $result` a variable that holds the word/name in between the first set of `[]` and another variable that holds the second set of `[]` then a third variable that holds everything between the last `_` and `.wav`. So it will have these variables:

```
$result_classname = spacer
$result_parent = timespacer
$result_name = fiveseconds
$result = [spacer]_[timespacer]_fiveseconds.wav
```

Which would allow me to do:

```
foreach ($result as $result) {
  echo "<a class='" . $result_classname . "' href='" . $result . "'>" . $result_name . "</a><span>" . $result_parent . "</span><br>";
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't want to use the same variable in your `foreach`:

```
foreach ($result as $result) {
```

Use a different variable:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
```

Then, here is a non regex way to handle this:

```
list($classname, $parent, $name) = explode('_', $value);
$classname = trim($classname, '[]');
$parent    = trim($parent, '[]');
$name      = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

- explode on underscores
- trim `[]` characters from each end
- get the filename without extenstion

Or a simple regex:

```
preg_match('/\[([^\]]+)\]_\[([^\]]+)\]_([^.]+).*/', $value, $matches);
```

Then use `print_r($matches);` to see which ones to use (`$matches[0]`, etc.).

Comment: Hey I just tried your code! And it is working partially. I am sure it is me who is doing something wrong. I added your code into the `foreach` and above the `echo` it now shows the name correctly but the parent & classname not. I will be uploading the code in the main article as it is now. So it can be understood better then my gibberish ;-)

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part.  Check the new `trim()` lines.

Comment: I went for the preg match which works perfect. Tried the other method as well but the link gave me `array` instead of the link. I want to thank you for redoing your initial answer and obviously for helping me out with tackling this issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Going to try it also with those new `trim()` lines.

Comment: Also, make sure to use `$value` in foreach and all lines after.

Comment: So I just tried with the new `trim()` but classname and parent are both blank. So going to use the `preg_match` or is it bad to use that one?

Comment: I just saw the code change in your answer. Tried the `trim()` again and now it works. Thanks man. But now the question which way is better? `trim()` or `preg_match`?